# C# WPF text alignment between multiple listboxes

Tags: wpf, forms

I want to create a 6 column form that aligns the data between all columns when scrolling.

I currently have 6 listboxes with powershell commands and it inputs fine to the listboxes, but when I scroll on any listbox the other listboxes does not move with it.

Oh it is a dashboard with auto refresh.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It may help you get an answer if you tag the correct technology. It looks like you need WPF(Windows Presentation Foundation) not WFP (Windows Filtering Platform).

To answer your question. It sounds like you need to set scroll related properties on the ListBoxes to false or none and nest your ListBoxes inside a ScrollViewer.

Hope that helps.

Here is an example window that shows the concept.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Grid.Column="0">
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 1"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 2"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 3"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 4"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 5"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 6"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 7"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 8"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 9"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 10"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 11"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 12"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 13"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 14"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 15"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line A 16"/>
            </ListBox>
            <ListBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Grid.Column="1">
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 1"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 2"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 3"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 4"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 5"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 6"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 7"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 8"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 9"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 10"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 11"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 12"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 13"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 14"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 15"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line B 16"/>
            </ListBox>
            <ListBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" Grid.Column="2">
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 1"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 2"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 3"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 4"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 5"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 6"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 7"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 8"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 9"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 10"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 11"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 12"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 13"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 14"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 15"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Line C 16"/>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you explain how to set scroll related properties on the ListBoxes to false or none and nest your ListBoxes inside a ScrollViewer.